# How to start jboss using jbos-as-maven plugin?

Tags: maven, jboss7.x

I'm trying to start jboss using maven build. following is my plugin configuration

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.Final</version>
            <configuration>
               <serverName>all</serverName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I have set the JBOSS_HOME variable also. But mvn jboss:start-and-wait fails with following error.

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jboss-maven-plugin:1.5.0:start-and-wait (default-cli) on project sub_project_a: Unable to get JBoss JMX MBean connection: Receive timed out -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jboss-maven-plugin:1.5.0:start-and-wait (default-cli) on project sub_project_a: Unable to get JBoss JMX MBean connection: Receive timed out
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to get JBoss JMX MBean connection: Receive timed out
at org.codehaus.mojo.jboss.StartAndWaitMojo.execute(StartAndWaitMojo.java:151)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
... 19 more
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out]
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.discoverServer(NamingContext.java:1302)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1382)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:579)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:572)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
at org.codehaus.mojo.jboss.StartAndWaitMojo.execute(StartAndWaitMojo.java:134)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out
at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.peekData(Native Method)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:675)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.discoverServer(NamingContext.java:1272)
... 26 more
```

mvn jboss:start indicate it is a success but server don't start.

Can anyone help 
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a mix of things here. The `org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin` does not have a `start-and-wait` goal. Also the prefix is `jboss-as`. Lastly there is no `serverName` configuration option.

It appears that you're using the codehaus [jboss-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/) which is different than the [jboss-as-maven-plugin](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/).